# Analyse device logs in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, device

My application crashed and I find the logs in Window>Devices>View Device logs but I don't understand these logs :

```
Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   Imagina_Connect                 0x00000001002192f4 0x10008c000 + 1626868
1   Imagina_Connect                 0x0000000100218dac 0x10008c000 + 1625516
2   Imagina_Connect                 0x00000001000990d8 0x10008c000 + 53464
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182c0d4bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182c0d47c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182c1b914 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182c1b0b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182e25470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182e25020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182d5cb48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182e25530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182e25020 start_wqthread + 4
```

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: Hi. Your app is named 'Imagina_Connect'? You need to symbolicate this crash-log.

Comment: Yes I know but how use this value : 0x00000001000990d8 0x10008c000 + 53464 for find the file and the line number ?

Comment: It's called the 'symbolicate' - you need the dSYM for that. See this gist [https://gist.github.com/Mozilla9/362024a3077438553f42](https://gist.github.com/Mozilla9/362024a3077438553f42)